# How to refresh the page after form submission?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I used fade dialog to display a form, and it can submit the form via `ajax` to create a new record in database.

And I am trying to refresh my page after `ajax` success. However, the page do not refresh with using Javascript(E.g. `location.replace etc`).

Ajax:

```
function callDatabase(action)
{
    var pn = $('#PN').val();
    var pp = $('#PP').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"databaseFunction.php",
        data:{action: action, pn: pn, pp: pp},
        success:function(msg){
           window.location.reload();
        }
    });

}
```

HTML:

```
p>          
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addData">Insert Data</button>
    </p>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="addData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="addLabel">Insert Data</h4>
          </div>
        <form id="insertForm" >
          <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="PN">ProductName</label>
                <input type="string" class="form-control" id="PN" placeholder="ProductName">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="PP">ProductPrice</label>
                <input type="string" class="form-control" id="PP" placeholder="ProductPrice">
              </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" onclick="callDatabase('insert')" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

How can I refresh the page after I submitted the form?

Comment: Yes...I tried before. But it didn't work too.

Comment: Try passing the true argument into the function. Eg: `location.reload(true);`

Answer (score 0):

You can change `'type=submit'` to `'type=button'`. Because a form will call  submit-Event of form, if you already call ajax to submit, you should cancel  submit of form.